# System wide Exception with WHERE and WHY enum.What are the benefits If any

Tags: java, exception, enums, jax-rs

I recently came across norm of a SystemWide Exception class with enum for failure types

```
Class SystemWideException extends RuntimeException{
 ErrorCause cause; //enum
 ErrorCode code; //enum
 Module where;  //enum
 Map<key,value> properties map
```

...
Here is how it is thrown

```
throw new SystemException(ThisModule.moduleX,ErrorCause.causeY,Errorcode.codeZ)
  .set("field", field)
  .set("value", value)
  .set("min-length", MIN_LENGTH);
}
```

A system wide exception can be useful like the one mentioned [here](https://northconcepts.com/blog/2013/01/18/6-tips-to-improve-your-exception-handling/) **but i doubt if there is any use to have the component where exception occured and why it occured in the exception object?**

I have a restful web service where i use a [ExceptionMapper](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html).I can use central logging here and the stacktrace gives why and where.Information about response status and body come from the exception object

Is there any use case where it would be meaningful to have Component,What,Why in the exception object?

Update: one use i have seen is multilingual support of error messages where Component+Error code form the key

Comment: As far as I know, not unless you're giving more specific/detailed information than the stacktrace will give. Though it is theoretically possible if someone else uses the program that, if they run into an exception they are not given that stacktrace?